# Failed to start kibana service. Error: Cannot find module '@kbn/apm-config-loader'

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, kibana, nvm, wazuh

I am working on Kibana and Elasticsearch. I was creating my own plugin following different tutorials but still hang on this work. During the creation of plugin through kibana-plugin-generator I have installed many other things to generate plugin like yarn nvm etc etc. but still fail to generate. After that when I start kibana service the following error occurs:
kindly help me to resolve this:

[Failed to start kibana service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iunf8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to build a custom version of Wazuh kibana plugin, or a new kibana plugin unrelated to wazuh?

From the logs it seems a dependency is missing. You could try installing the yarn dependencies with:

```
# yarn kbn clean 
# yarn kbn bootstrap
```

This would bootsrap it again and download the dependencies.

I hope this solves your question. Cheers